# How can i access to application context from a web service implementation

Tags: java, web-services, applicationcontext

i'm having problem with web services. I have the endpoint class and the implementation class as follow:

Endpoint:

```
@WebService
public class LogExposer {
private LogExposerManager manager;

public boolean Login(String username, String password) {
    return manager.doLogin(username, password);
}

public String documentJSONLog(Long idDocument) {
    return manager.documentJSONLog(idDocument);
}

public String getService() {
    return manager.getService();
}   
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class LogExposerManager implements LogExposerInterface {

private JSONObject JSONLog;
@Autowired
protected ApplicationContext context;
private boolean autorized = false;

/**
 * @param username Username used for the login operation
 * @param password The password for the user
 * @return
 */
@Override
public boolean doLogin(String username, String password) {
    autorized = username.equals(password);
    try {
         Service service = (Service) context.getBeans("service");
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        autorized = false;
    }
    
    return autorized;
}

/**
 * @param idDocument
 * @return The JSON rappresentation of the documentlog file
 */
@Override
public String documentJSONLog(Long idDocument) {
    JSONLog = new JSONObject();
    JSONLog.put("Document id:", idDocument);
    return JSONLog.toString();
}

/**
 * @return
 */
@Override
public String getService() {
    
    return "";
}

}
```

However i can't used the ApplicationContext because it is null.
How can i access to the ApplicationContext from this class?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I find how to retrieve the application context:

```
WebApplicationContext context = ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
Service service = context.getBean(Service.class);
```